# returning a string from a function that the user inputs

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, output

I have been searching around the web for returning a string in a function.

```
const char *func()
{
  const char *s1 = "hello";
  return s1;
}
```

This works if you predefine the string. How do I let the user input a string and return that specific string

```
const char *func()
{
  char s1[313];
  cin >> s1;
  return s1;
}
```

I tried the above but it gave the warning

```
warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable
  's1' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
return s1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either allocate a character array inside the function or pass an array as an argument to the function.

In the first case you can either use standard class std::string or you will need to allocate the array your self.

For example

```
std ::string func()
{
  std::string s1;
  cin >> s1;
  return s1;
}
```

or

```
char * func()
{
   const size_t N = 313;

   char *s1 = new char[N];
   cin.getline( s1, N );

   return s1;
}
```

in the second case the function can look the following way

```
char * func( char s1[], size_t n )
{
   cin.getline( s1, n );
   return s1;
}
```

and in main it could be called as

```
int main()
{
   const size_t N = 313;
   char s1[N];

   func( s1, N );
}
```

Comment: For the second one(where memory is allocated), is there a way to delete s1 after returning s1. It seems that after you return s1, it exits out of the function so you cannot deallocate the memory.

Comment: @user3239138  If a memory was allocated with using operator new you can always deaalocate it using operator delete or delete [] if you have a pointer that refers to this memory.

Comment: I understand that. However, it seems that we cannot delete the pointer before returning it. In the second example  we have deallocate s1 but we have to return it first. So my thought was to put the delete s1 after the return s1. But returns s1 exits us out of the function and the memory is still not allocated.

Comment: @user3239138 You need to delete a pointer that points to memory allocated with operator new.

Answer (score 4):

One easy way to do it would be to use an `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string func()
{
  std::string s1;
  std::cin >> s1;
  return s1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way of doing this in C++ is to use an `std::string`, as juanchopanza said, but just FYI, one could achieve this without `std::string`s via something like this:

```
char* func() {
  char* s1 = new char[313];    // allocate memory on the heap
  cin >> s1;
  return s1;
}
```

Though this has the stipulation of requiring the caller to `delete[]` the result of the function:

```
char* s = func();
// do stuff with s
delete[] s;  // must be called eventually
```

Don't ever do this in actual C++ code though -- use `std::string`.